# Google Tasks API: Uncaught exception 'Google_ServiceException'

Tags: php, credentials, google-tasks-api

I'm getting the following message:

> 'Uncaught exception 'Google_ServiceException' with message 'Error calling GET `https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/users/@me/lists`: (403) Insufficient Permission''.

I'm using OAuth 2.0 and it works fine with the Calendar API, but the Tasks API with the same credentials throws the above exception. (I'm trying to run the example file coming with the api library.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', function() {
      gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get().execute(function(resp) {
        console.log(resp.name);
        gapi.client.load('tasks', 'v1', function(res) {
            gapi.client.request({
              'path': '/tasks/v1/users/@me/lists',
              'callback': YourCallBackFunction
            });
        });
      });
    });
```